# XNA Buffer Best Practice

Tags: c#, xna

I am currently converting a 2D game to 3D, never having worked with 3D before I am trying to learn as I go. I am wondering what the best way to use vertex/index buffers is.

Currently I am looping through a grid and creating a set of buffers for each tile type, these are then used in the draw method. Im presuming I shouldnt use multiple sets of vertex buffers but dont know of another way to do this, as each tile is a different texture.

Grid loop

```
for (int i = Convert.ToInt32(xPos / 2) - 30; i < Convert.ToInt32(xPos / 2) + 30; i++)
        {
            for (int a = Convert.ToInt32(yPos / 2); a < Convert.ToInt32(yPos / 2) + 50; a++)
            {
                if (mapXtile > 0 && mapYtile > 0 && mapXtile < Globals.mapsizex && mapYtile < Globals.mapsizey)
                {
                    int currentTile = Globals.levelArray[level, mapXtile, mapYtile].TyleType;

                    if (currentTile == tyleType.grass)
                    {
                        createCubeVertices(i * 2, a * 2, 1, 0f, count, grassVertices);
                        SetUpBufferIndices(count, grassIndices);
                        count++;
                    }

                    if (currentTile == tyleType.water)
                    {
                        createCubeVertices(i * 2, a * 2, 1, 0f, count, waterVertices);
                        SetUpBufferIndices(count, waterIndices);
                        waterCount++;
                    }
                }
                mapYtile = mapYtile + 1;
                //mapYtile++;
            }
            mapXtile = mapXtile + 1;
            mapYtile = Convert.ToInt32(yPos / 2);
        }
CopyToBuffers(grassVertices, grassIndices);
CopyToWaterBuffers(waterVertices, waterIndices);
```

Draw code

```
   foreach (EffectPass pass in grassEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();

            device.Indices = myIndexBuffer;
            device.SetVertexBuffer(myVertexBuffer);
            device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, grassVertices.Length, 0, grassIndices.Length/3);  
        }

        foreach (EffectPass pass in mouseEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();

            device.Indices = myWaterIndexBuffer;
            device.SetVertexBuffer(myWaterVertexBuffer);
            device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, 10000, 0, 10000);
        }
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options:

1. **Single atlas texture.** Advantages: easy, fast, default shaders can be used. Disadvantages: texture seams.
2. **Multitexturing.** Advantages: powerful and flexible, you control everything. Disadvantages: more complex, custom shaders, slower.

Answer (score 0):

if you are asing the same effect for painting them, you can use an [atlas texture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas) and group all primitives into one unique vertexbuffer, allowing to draw all in a single call.